# Equivalent of --rosdep-install in Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there. Quick question.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with ROS Fuerte. Is there any download/install command which recognizes the nested dependencies in a repository/download source that can automatically download those as well? I sincerely don't desire to download all nested dependencies individually.

I tried using rosmake --rosdep-install but met failure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36746/equivalent-of---rosdep-install-in-fuerte/) by [MikeJohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2643/mikejohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MikeJohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2643/mikejohnson/) on 2012-06-18**:
For example, if I want to install the stack "object_recognition", which has many dependencies, how exactly would I do that conveniently?

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-18**:
rosdep install your_package_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just call rosdep before you call rosmake with the same arguments.  We removed the ability to automatically call through for cleaner dependency trees and clearer purpose.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2